# How to get FilePath from Ecore Resource

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

How to get file path from resource(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource) instance ?

Comment: I have got the solution: we can use  EcorePlatformUtil.getFile(resourceInstance); From this file get the path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getURI` method of the `Resource` interface to get the resource's location. This may be a file or it may be another form of URI depending on how the resource was created.

If the `URI` uses the `platform` protocol you can convert it to a `file` protocol using `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator`:

```
FileLocator.toFileURL(uri.toURL());
```

Comment: getURI - will return path in the formate :"Platform:/relative path". I need complete path .

Comment: Added platform protocol conversion

Comment: URI instance is from "org.eclipse.emf.common.util" it does not have 'toURL' API in it.  Instead we can use EcorePlatformUtil.getFile(resourceInstance); From the file instance we can get the location.

Answer (score 0):

try to do:

```
    var libraryFile = ""

    val theRelativeFile = resource.URI.trimFileExtension.appendFileExtension('asm')

    if (resource.URI.isPlatform) {
        libraryFile = ResourcesPlugin.workspace.root.getFile(new Path(theRelativeFile.toPlatformString(true))).rawLocation.toOSString   
    }               
    else {
        libraryFile = resource.resourceSet.URIConverter.normalize(theRelativeFile).toFileString
    }
```